# How to import socket.io.client javascript in polymer 3 PWA starter kit app for server build

Tags: sockets, socket.io, polymer, web-component

I am using a socket.io-client connection in my web component and need to import the socket.io-client java library ([socket.io-client github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)).

```
Usage in web-component: var socket =  io.connect(socket_url);
```

All ways to import the socket.io-client.js fail with using different import variants like the one below directly in my web component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
```

I searched and found ([solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53166919/9192527)) that socket.io-client provides no ES modules which polymer requires for import. The proposed solution taken from this answer suggests to include the socket.io javascript directly in the main index.html. So I am now importing the socket.io-client script in my index.html with

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.slim.js" crossorigin></script>
```

This solution works in development and testing with:

```
npm start
```

The build works and the application and socket implementation is working as expected at http://127.0.0.1:8081 in the browser.

But when I start the build process for production and serve with:

```
npm run build:prpl-server
npm run serve:prpl-server
...
prpl-server listening http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

The build is successful but the application **fails to run in browser** with the following error in the console:

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “http://127.0.0.1:8080/es6-bundled/node_assets/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.slim.js”.

So the socket.io...js file is not put/copied into the build folders during the build process. There is even no node_assets folder in the build directory. However the code and testing works - so the import and script seems to work correctly. I am doing something wrong for the final build but dont understand what.

So the question is how to correctly import the socket.io-client javascript in the index.html or web component to correctly output it into the final build?

Comment: I think you need to add `"node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/**"` to the `extraDependencies` part of the polymer.json in order for the build process to take the files in account

Comment: simple. That did it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it and close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `"node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/**"` to the `extraDependencies` part of the polymer.json in order for the build process to take the files in account

It would look something like this

```
{
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/**",
    "push-manifest.json",
    "node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/**"
  ]
}
```